# Two different degrees for a ODE

Tags: calculus, ordinary-differential-equations, irreducible-polynomials

According to [Wikipedia](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Degree_of_a_differential_equation),

> The degree of a differential equation is the power of its highest derivative, after the equation has been made rational and integral in all of its derivatives.

Using this definition we find that the degree of the following ODE is 2. $$\left(\frac {d^3y}{dx^3}\right)^2-\frac {dy}{dx}+5=0$$
We can also express the above ODE as follows,
$$\left(\frac {d^3y}{dx^3}\right)^6-\left(\frac {dy}{dx}-5\right)^3=0$$ But using the same definition we get that the degree is 6. Can someone explain why the degree is not 6.

**Edit-1**
Instead of squaring I cubed the initial ODE.
**Edit-2**
I understood from the comments that they are different DE, so is there any point in asking to find the degree of $$\left(\frac {d^3y}{dx^3}\right)-\sqrt {\frac {dy}{dx}+5}=0$$

Comment: "Power" is a bad term. They should have said it is the **degree** of the highest derivative. In both cases the highest degree is a *third* derivative, so it is a *third* order ODE.

Comment: @K.defaoite Can you please explain why the degree is not 4.

Comment: According to the terminology I learned, the equation is third order, fourth degree.  The order is the order of the highest derivative appearing.  The degree is the degree if the equation is view as a polynomial in the derivatives.  So we can have a linear (first-order) third degree equation for instance.

Comment: @saulspatz  So the degree depends on how you express the equation. Am I correct?

Comment: @Asher2211 I wouldn't say that.  Then the degree wouldn't be well-defined.  I don't think I've ever seen a complete formal definition of degree, but I'm sure that in your example, the degree is $2$.  Perhaps the polynomial should be irreducible.

Comment: $ \left(\frac {d^3y}{dx^3}\right)^2-\left(\frac {dy}{dx}-5\right)=0\implies \left(\frac {d^3y}{dx^3}\right)^4-\left(\frac {dy}{dx}-5\right)^2=0 $

That doesn't mean both are same differential equations and need to have same degree

If you think both are same differential equations then, $({dy \over dx})=c$ and $({dy \over dx})^2=c^2$ and $({dy \over dx})^3=c^3$ and $({dy \over dx})^n=c^n$, all should be same same differential equations according to you.

Comment: If you wrote derivatives with primes, (e.g., $f(x), f^\prime (x), f^{\prime\prime} (x)$ and so on), when you expand the equation fully, ask what is the largest number of primes on any term.  Thus $(f^\prime (x))^9$ is a first-order ODE.

Comment: Yes, $(f^\prime (x))^9$ is a first order ODE, but what about its degree? Shouldn't it be 9 since the highest order derivative is $f^\prime (x)$ in that ODE and its power is 9.

Comment: No:  Write it out:  $(f^\prime (x))^9 = f^\prime (x) f^\prime (x) f^\prime (x) f^\prime (x) f^\prime (x) f^\prime (x) f^\prime (x) f^\prime (x) f^\prime (x)$.  What is the largest number of primes on any term that you see?  ANSWER:  *ONE*.  Or:  How many derivatives will you ever have to compute???  Just ONE.

Comment: @DavidG.Stork I want to know why the degree (not order) of the ODE mentioned in the question changes when I square it.

Comment: Honestly I've never heard of this notion of degree nor seen a reason why anyone should care about it. The main thing I would care about with a nonlinearity in the highest derivative is simply "can the equation be written in the form $y^{(n)}=f(\dots)$ where $n$ is the order?". And the answer to that is "no" if the degree is well-defined and even. (In particular, raising both sides of an ODE to an even power changes it in a way that actually does matter.)

Comment: both the ODE are different so different degree's. Are the equations $x^2=3$ and $x^4=9$ are same?

Comment: @DSD Can you answer my second edit?

Comment: @Asher2211  in the second edit, the degree of the differential equation is 2.

Comment: @DSD Wouldn't it be 6 if I raise it to the power of 6 instead of squaring it.

Answer (score 2):

A DE has the form of an algebraic equation of degree $m$ in the highest derivative, then we say that the given DE is of degree $m$. Regarding your question in $\textbf{Edit-2}.$  Rewrite the equation $\displaystyle \left(\frac{d^3y}{dx^3}\right)=\sqrt{\frac{dy}{dx}-5}$.  Now taking $2m\, (m \in \mathbb{N})$ powers both sides we obtain  $\displaystyle \left(\frac{d^3y}{dx^3}\right)^{2m}=\left(\frac{dy}{dx}-5\right)^m$. This a  polynomial in $\displaystyle \frac{d^3y}{dx^3}$ with highest degree $2m$ for each $m\in \mathbb{N}$. So degree of the above differential equation is $2m$. For each $m\in \mathbb{N}$, $2m$ is a degree. But, degree of a polynomial is unique. To fix the uniqueness of the degree, take the lowest power which reduces the equation into a polynomial.  Thus, the degree of the above DE is 2.